# Golang installation broke my zsh prompt macos

Tags: macos, go, zsh, macos-sierra, oh-my-zsh

I installed `golang` from `.dmg` and it broke my zsh prompt (if I try bash it works ok).
I have the following line in `.bash_profile`

```
export PS1='[\u@\h \w$(__git_ps1)]\n\$ '
```

But when I echo my `$PS1` it equals `%m%#`, as well as `$PROMPT`.
I am sure it happened after install of go.
My $THEME is empty.
Macos: Sierra 10.12.6
Go: go1.10 darwin/amd64

How does this work?

Comment: I also found that my $PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin. How did go/bin appeared there?

Comment: .dmg is on a Mac? is that right?  Please add version of go you installed and version of Mac operating system.  Then someone can try and replicate

Comment: edit the body of the question and add this info

Comment: `.bash_profile` is not used by `zsh`, and the value of `PS1` shown is a perfectly valid zsh prompt. What exactly is broken?